# getting this error while post request ValidationError: name: Path `name` is required., tech: Path `tech` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

`alien.js`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const alienSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tech: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  sub: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
  },
});
export default mongoose.model("Alien", alienSchema);
```

`aliens.js`

```
import express from "express";
import Alien from "../models/alien.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const aliens = await Alien.find();
    res.json(aliens);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Error" + err);
  }
});
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const alien = new Alien({
    name: req.body.name,
    tech: req.body.tech,
    sub: req.body.sub,
  });
  try {
    const a1 = await alien.save();
    res.json(a1);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Error" + err);
  }
});
export default router;
```

Comment: your `req.body.name ` is empty and you are getting mongoose validation error as its a required field in the schema

Comment: {
    "name":'abc',
    'tech':'node js'
} this object "POST" at end point in postman